# Regular Expression problem in erb Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I need to apply a regular expression in html.erb

```
<% taxon_name.strains.each do |strain| %>
<% taxon_name.strain_appendices.each_with_index do |strain_appendice, i| %>
<% if ((strain_appendice.data_source =~ /LPSN/) && (strain.relevance =~ /^ty(.*)ain$/))%>
<% if i == 0 %>
<p><%= strain_appendice.appendix %>  </p> <% strain.strain_id %> <% strain.relevance %>
<%else%>
<%= strain_appendice.appendix %> - <% strain.strain_id %> <% strain.relevance %>
<%end%>
<%end%>
```

This code replaces the all content of a strain.strain_id & strain.relevance and doesnot passes match criteria. Instead of matching it replacing strain.strain_id & strain.relevance contents.

Kindly tell me the way to match and pass conditions.

-- 
With Regards,

Palani Kannan. K,

Comment: you mean you just want to match, but don't know why it is replacing instead?

Comment: There are no really question :(

Comment: Did you notice, that this piece of code: `<% strain.strain_id %> <% strain.relevance %>` doesn't print anything? There's no `<%=` at the beginning.

Comment: Also, if I were you I'd refactor this code by moving the looping/matching code into the `taxon_name` model. It could build a collection of matching `strain` and `strain_appendice` object pairs. Then you'd do a simple loop in the view which would just print them.

Comment: @Matt: I included "="... its still not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code is working for me if I add two `<%end%>` statements at the end, like this:

```
<% taxon_name.strains.each do |strain| %>
  <% taxon_name.strain_appendices.each_with_index do |strain_appendice, i| %>
    <% if ((strain_appendice.data_source =~ /LPSN/) && (strain.relevance =~ /^ty(.*)ain$/))%>
      <% if i == 0 %>
        <p><%= strain_appendice.appendix %>  </p> <%= strain.strain_id %> <%= strain.relevance %>
      <%else%>
        <%= strain_appendice.appendix %> - <%= strain.strain_id %> <%= strain.relevance %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

Comment: **Two** additional `end` tags. If it doesn't work, maybe your data doesn't match the regexp. I tested this code with data that matched and it worked.